# JqGrid MultiSearch dialog add button hidden

Tags: jqgrid

with code like this:

```
$gird.navGrid("#pager", {"add":false,"edit":false,"del":false,"view":false}, {},{},{},{},{"multipleSearch":true,"overlay":false}
```

If I click the 'find' icon, the add button for adding a rule is hidden. IE here is the HTML from firebug:

```
<tr>
    <th align="left" colspan="5">
        <select class="opsel">
            <option selected="selected" value="AND">AND</option>
            <option value="OR">OR</option>
        </select>
        <span></span>
        <input type="button" class="add-rule ui-add" title="Add rule" value="+" style="display: none;">
    </th>
</tr>
```

If I add this:

```
$gird.searchGrid({"multipleSearch":true,"overlay":false});
```

Thee button is visible. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes things which look very strange can be solved very easy. The problem is that the `searchGrid` parameters `{"multipleSearch":true,"overlay":false}` are in another position of [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator#definition). Currently the settings will be interpret as `prmView` and not as `prmSearch`. You should remove one `{}` parameter:

```
$gird.jqGrid('navGrid', '#locationPager',
             {add:false,edit:false,del:false,view:false},
             {},{},{},{multipleSearch:true,overlay:false});
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg. Silly mistake. But doesn't that seem like odd behaviour?

Comment: @Fatmuemoo: It is just the default behavior. The default value of `multipleSearch` is `false` and the button for the rule is hidden.